# Custom lucene search syntax

Tags: search, syntax, lucene

I am trying to achieve multiple partial word search on a single field. My search syntax looks like below.

```
Dim terms = searchstring.Trim().Split(" "c).Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).[Select](Function(x) x.Trim() + "* &&")
        searchstring = String.Join(" ", terms)
        searchResults = LuceneSearch.SearchDefault(searchstring, "Address")
```

The result I am getting is below

http://s13.postimg.org/80kdhapt3/result.jpg

The result I am trying to achieve is below

http://s23.postimg.org/40i9wewbf/resultto_achieve.jpg

As you can see I am searching for "Bank Station London". I have entered "Bank" and "Station" in full but "Londo" partial. Even though I have used AND operator it ignored the third word as it only partially matches. Is there any way to achieve this. Even if the word is partial the probability/ranking is based on all three words.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at what the generated `searchstring` looks like, in order to debug?  Seeing that would likely be helpful.

Comment: The generated searchstring is Bank* && Station* && London* or (Londo*). If I replace * with ~, it is still not returning result including third partial word.

Comment: Which looks alright, in terms of standard search syntax.  In that case, I think the problem may be in what `LuceneSearch.SearchDefault` is doing. Can you post code from there?  I wonder if it might be escaping the search string passed into it, or something of that nature.